How to give an inputs to a deep learning model where the inputs are of image as well as landmark xy cordinates?
well I am trying to make deep model based on taking input of images as well as cordinates of the images that x,y espcially human pose.Is possible to give both as input to a model or not.If possible state a method.
I want method of taking inputs from both images as well as corrdinates of images
